# .NET 5.0 Blazor IStringLocalizer and case sensitivity

Tags: .net-core, localization, blazor-server-side, case-sensitive

I'm using a `IStringLoclizer` approach with a `resx` file containing key-value pairs to localize my app as decribed in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

I've just discovered that:

On the one hand the `.resx` file is case **insensitive** (storing the key `Firstname` and `FirstName` will throw an error of key already existing).

On the second hand, when I want to RETRIEVE the keys, it **IS** case sensitive (if the key `Firstname` exists and I want to get the value of `FirstName`, the value is not retrieved by `IStringLoclizer` - which makes sense from the key-value pair point of view!).

Is there a way to override the `IStringLocalizer` getters, in order to implement some logic (e.g. change all keys to lowercase, and search any key by lowercase)? The key of a valid solution is to avoid changing all keys in the `.resx` file AND wherever I call the `IStringLocalizer`.

**Edit**
I found out about `ResourceManager.IgnoreCase` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.ignorecase?view=net-5.0), but it is not clear to me how to access the resource manager - probably this has to be done in `Startup.cs` somehow?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by overwriting the `ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory`.

```cs
public class CaseInsensitiveResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory : ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory
    {
        public CaseInsensitiveResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory(IOptions<LocalizationOptions> localizationOptions, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) : base(localizationOptions, loggerFactory)
        {
        }

        //unfortunately we need to use reflection to the the ResourceManager as the field is private 
        private readonly FieldInfo _field = typeof(ResourceManagerStringLocalizer).GetField("_resourceManager", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        //override this method to access the resource manager at the time it is created
        protected override ResourceManagerStringLocalizer CreateResourceManagerStringLocalizer(Assembly assembly, string baseName)
        {
            //call the base method to get the localizer, I would like to override this implementation but the fields used in the construction are private
            var localizer = base.CreateResourceManagerStringLocalizer(assembly, baseName);
            if (_field == null) return localizer;
            //set the resource manager to ignore case
            if (_field.GetValue(localizer) is ResourceManager resourceManager) resourceManager.IgnoreCase = true;
            return localizer;
        }
    }
```

The you need to register the factory **before** you add the localization.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizerFactory, CaseInsensitiveResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory>();
            services.AddLocalization(options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

            //other service configurations....
    }
```

I hope in the future these classes are made more extensible. Private fields in both in `ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory` and `ResourceManagerStringLocalizer` necessitates reflection.

Comment: While this does work well, it will use more memory and possibly be a performance decrease according to MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.ignorecase?view=net-7.0

Although after benchmark testing this code myself on .NET6 I actually noticed a performance increase for the case-matched case of around 20%. A decrease for the case-mismatched case of 10%. But for memory, I saw about a 400% increase. Since this does use reflection it makes sense why the memory would be so much higher.